# React and responsive web sites

Tags: css, responsive-design, reactjs

is there any sample demonstrating a responsive web site built on React?
Want to have my site on Desktops and Smartphone, maybe tablet.
No it  isn't the next Facebook UI, it  is for very limited user circle, maintaining a measurement System.

With best regards

Gerhard

Comment: This is a question that is likely to get closed because it is not a question that has a clear answer on SO. Instead, it's asking for an offsite reference (and SO is not a substitute for Google). To salvage the question, try asking about a specific and sovable instance about which you have a question. Also take a look at Dan's good answer below.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of responsive sites built with React, but they are no different to responsive sites built with Angular, Ember or any other library. The bit that makes them responsive is CSS and media queries — not Javascript.

Mostly it's easier to work with a responsive grid, than by writing media queries yourself. Pick a CSS framework/library that offers a responsive grid (there are many), then look for examples of people using that specific framework and learn to use the responsive grid in a Javascript-free setting.

You'll find that you don't need Javascript to make a responsive site.

- React is **data**, **logic** and **structure**.
- CSS is **appearance** and **presentation**.

Answer (score 0):

Remind you, that SO is not the place where I can just put links.

But to answer your question: 
Yes, React can be use to make responsive website. Though the term "responsive" is more on the CSS layer.

Demo with some sample metrics:

http://www.gitchecker.com/dactylographsy/grunt-dactylographsy

The source:

https://github.com/madshargreave/gitchecker